# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.math.BigDecimal

Tags: postgresql, database-migration, spring-jdbc

I have changed the Data source of my Java project from Oracle to PostgreSQL. I was able to change the connection string successfully and was also able to place the new postgresql query.The columns returned both the old and new query is similar, so chance of any mismatch.But itsthrowing following exception :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.math.BigDecimal
    at 
*.JdbcTrialProvider.mileStoneCountTypeFactory(JdbcTrialProvider.java:425)
    at *.tr002.providers.JdbcTrialProvider.milestonesTypeFactory(JdbcTrialProvider.java:360)
    at *.providers.JdbcTrialProvider.getTrialCharacteristicsByTrialNumber(JdbcTrialProvider.java:277)
    at*test.InfoHubTest.test(InfoHubTest.java:102)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

on using `milestone.setForecasted(((BigDecimal) forecasted).intValueExact())`

Please let me know if more info is required.

Comment: My guess is that `forecasted` is an `Integer` so you don't need to convert in a `BigDecimal`  and then again to an `Integer`

Comment: forecasted  is of Object type

Comment: @Renato Thanks . It helped . Check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing `milestone.setForecasted(((BigDecimal) forecasted).intValueExact())` 
with `milestone.setForecasted((Integer)forecasted)` did the trick.